# How to exclude part of doc comment from being displayed in generated Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

In our project, we are going to write the API javadocs. In the doc comments apart from the method details we want to write the history details. For example, if a method was modified for fixing a particular issue, we want to document the details of the issue along with the javadoc comment for that method.

```
/**
 * Displays the details for a valid registered customer against the specified <code>Integer customerId</code>.<br>
 * Responsible to check the existance of the customer before sending back the information for the "Customer Reference" screen.
 * 
 * @param customerId the customer id to fetch the details for
 * @return <code>jsp</code> file name for "Customer Reference" screen along with Customer details
 * 
 * BTS-1947 | custom fields not displayed correctly | 25-10-2016 | Vaibhav
 */
public String displayCustomerInfo(Integer customerId) {
```

The problem is, we do not want to display the part `BTS-1947 | custom fields not displayed correctly | 25-10-2016 | Vaibhav` in the generated javadocs with javadocs tool. Is it possible to do so or is there a better way to maintain the update history with javadocs?

Comment: What value does that comment provide over your source control history?

Comment: I feel the same way, but I was asked to provide solution for this as my manager wants other developers to know the history by looking at the code itself rather than source control history (SVN in our case). We write the normal multi-line comment for the history part /*...*/ but this does not look good to write two different kind of comments one above the other.

Comment: Why not put that info on a different, non-javadoc comment right above the javadoc one?

Comment: That is what currently I'm doing as I didn't find any other solution as of now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jdk1.7 you can use a custom tag. When javadoc compiles, it doesn't show anything with a custom tag. It will give you a warning though.
For example:

```
/**
* Displays the details for a valid registered customer against the specified <code>Integer customerId</code>.<br>
* Responsible to check the existance of the customer before sending back the information for the "Customer Reference" screen.
* 
* @param customerId the customer id to fetch the details for
* @return <code>jsp</code> file name for "Customer Reference" screen along with Customer details
* 
* @custom BTS-1947 | custom fields not displayed correctly | 25-10-2016 | Vaibhav
*/
public String displayCustomerInfo(Integer customerId) {
```

**jdk1.8 will give error while compiling javadoc with custom tag.**

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: Hi @observer, thanks for reply. But we are using JDK 1.8.